# Android - Как получить полный список файлов из папки и её подпапок?

Tags: android, java, файлы

Здравствуйте! У меня есть папка `SR_Data`, в которой лежат подпапки, в каждой примерно по 20 файлов. В SR_Data файлы тоже есть. Вопрос заключается в этом: как получить список файлов из папки и её подпапок?

Comment: Рекурсивно пробегать папки. В чём проблема то?

Comment: Дело в том, что я не умею это делать)

Comment: @SuperCreeper файлы в InternalStorage или External? Или в assets?

Comment: @woesss, пожалуйста, добавьте это как ответ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Дело в том, что я не умею это делать)**

Тогда смотрите один из вариантов реализации первого коммента:

```
public ArrayList<File> listFilesWithSubFolders(File dir) {
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
            files.addAll(listFilesWithSubFolders(file));
        else
            files.add(file);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: @woesss, спасибо большое!