# Метод для копирования всех баз данных в память телефона

Tags: sqlite, android

Можете скинуть\написать метод, который будет копировать все базы данных (файлы с расширением .db в память телефона  (`/storage/sdcard0/`)? В гугле рылся — не нашел! Просто не могу никак просмотреть все БД на телефоне без root`a.

Comment: Базы данных чужих приложений вы, слава богу, достать без рута не сможете. Никак.

Comment: @metalurgus, мне мои только нужны. Для дебага.

Comment: вам на самом деле нужно решить 2 задачи: 1) Рекурсивно найти файлы с определенным расширением в определенной директории. 2) скопировать их на карту памяти.

Comment: @metalurgus, я не умею вообще искать файлы...  :(

Comment: все мы чего-то не умеем. Как насчет научиться?

Comment: @metalurgus, научиться можно, но, в данной ситуации, мне важно быстро получить ответ. После того как допишу приложения — прочитаю нормальную книгу по Android`y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод вам врятли кто напишет, а вот алгоритм - легко:

1. Получаем путь к защищенному хранилищу файлов приложения
2. Пробегаемся по всем файлам, собирая те, у которых расширение  `.db`
3. Копируем файлы куда-нибудь.

С помощью гугла эти пункты вам несложно будет реализовать.

---

А ещё можно загуглить это:

> [copy apps databases on sd android programmatically](http://copy%20apps%20databases%20on%20sd%20android%20programmatically)

и получить [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490002/3212712):

```
// Copy to sdcard for debug use
    public static void copyDatabase(Context c, String DATABASE_NAME) {
        String databasePath = c.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        File f = new File(databasePath);
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        InputStream myInput = null;
        Log.d("testing", " testing db path " + databasePath);
        Log.d("testing", " testing db exist " + f.exists());

        if (f.exists()) {
            try {

                File directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DB_DEBUG");
                if (!directory.exists())
                    directory.mkdir();

                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/" + DATABASE_NAME);
                myInput = new FileInputStream(databasePath);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (myOutput != null) {
                        myOutput.close();
                        myOutput = null;
                    }
                    if (myInput != null) {
                        myInput.close();
                        myInput = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Все-таки еще денек понядеюсь (ведь не раз писали). Если никто не напишет - приму Ваш ответ.

Comment: Плохо гуглили - см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: Я искал на русском :(. Но вот проблема, тут же нужно указывать имя базы, а если я не знаю имени и сколько у меня баз, но нужно скопировать все базы?

Comment: Значит вам нужно загуглить первый пункт - узнать где хранятся базы данных (путь к папке) и составить массив из имён файлов в этой папке. После в цикле запустить метод из ответа для каждого имени базы данных из массива.

Comment: Вот такой способ прокатит без root'a - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276158/android-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA ?

Comment: Да, прокатит.....